# A question about irreducible representations of SO(3) group.

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, group-actions

I’m trying to understand  / classify the irreducible representations of the group $SO(3)$ but several resources I have found links directly to quantum mechanics and I don’t have enough basics. Could you help me to understand them? Or provide some reference which moves from the basics? (Maybe only assuming standard results of representation theory).

Comment: You didn't specify $SO(3,\Bbb{R})$? And which kind of representations you want: finite dimensional, unitary, continuous, algebraic..

Comment: Yes I'm talking about $SO(3,\mathbb{R})$ and *finite-dimensional*  representations